# power bi access token api working fine in postman but not working in angular app

Tags: angular, http-post, powerbi, postman, powerbi-embedded

I'm calling power bi API in postman which is working good and as an accepted result I'm getting.
while that app I'm calling in the angular app it's not working. 
I'm getting response null.

I have attached my code below,
Please help me out I have been trying to solve this issue last few days.

**API:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

Below is my angular code

```
getAccessToken(param): Observable<any> {

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  })
};

const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('resource', 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api')
  .set('client_id', 'xxxxxxxxx')
  .set('client_secret', 'xxxxxxxxx')
  .set('grant_type', 'password')
  .set('scope', 'openid')
  .set('username', 'xxxxxxxxx')
  .set('password', 'xxxxxxxxx');

return this.http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", body.toString(), httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response)
  );}
```

In the below reference image same API which is working good but not working in angular.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue and solution.

**Issue:**
why it's broken my API response 'null'.
The issue is that due to CORS, I used the CORS extension for crome it was deprecated.
so it was given the result 'null'

**Solution:**
I used the latest one CORS extension for chrome and that's resolved the issue temporarily. 
this is not a proper solution because we don't have the right to resolved cors issue in the backend.
if we need to solve it form our hand then we have to create API in .net for getting AccessToken and then that API we can consume in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting body as http parameters. Change to:

```
const body = {
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    grant_type: 'password',
    scope: 'openid',
    username: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
}

return this.http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", body, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response)
  );}
```

Comment: Hi Chrillewoodz, I tried same as you suggested but getting an error " 400 Bad Request "

Comment: @MitulPatel Are they expecting a string as the body?

Comment: I trying with 'HttpParams' it's getting status 200 (success) but getting response null

Comment: @MitulPatel Can you give me a link to the docs you're following?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-To-Get-embed-token-using-Get-Post-only/m-p/294475

Comment: Don't see anything indicating it should be a string.. Are you sure you're sending the correct information in the body? One or more properties could be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201247/discussion-between-mitul-patel-and-chrillewoodz).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header and body like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form- 
        urlencoded')
};

const params = {
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    grant_type: 'password',
    scope: 'openid',
    username: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
}

const body = `resource=${params.resource}&client_id=${params.client_id}&client_secret=${params.client_secret}&grant_type=${params.grant_type}& scope =${params.scope}&username =${params.username}&password =${params.password}`;

return this.http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", 
    body, httpOptions)
.pipe(
    map(response => response)
);
```

Comment: HI Banki, still same problem, I made changes as you suggested i got status code: 200 and response null

Comment: yes, I was getting CORS error and to solve i installed CORS extension in chrome so now I don't get cors error

Answer (score 0):

Since your trying it from client side angular end powerBI is not responding because of security issues, you can try triggering the call from server end like .net,nodejs,java, and then pass the data to angular.

since it works in POSTMAN, which is a server side, calling it from sever side technologies should work for you.